# Javascript reduce to a desire array using reduce and acc

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, accumulate

I have a list array

```
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
]
```

I want to reduce the array to only
[23,18,12,20]

I try to use reduce and accumulative

```
const newList = List.reduce(
 (acc, {age}) =>{
  acc = age 
  return acc
  },[]}
```

then the result only show the last age not accumulative at all, not sure what's the best way to do.

Comment: Using map() would be simpler ... `newList = List.map(({age}) => age)`

Comment: You could actually do this using `Array.prototype.map`.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `map` not `reduce`

```
const ages = List.map(item => item.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append an element to the array. `acc = age` only resets the accumulator each time.

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
]
const newList = List.reduce(
 (acc, {age}) =>{
  acc.push(age)
  return acc
  },[]);
console.log(newList);
```

This can also be done more simply using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which creates a new array by converting each element of the array to the return value of a callback to which the element is passed.

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
];
const res = List.map(({age})=>age);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although map() is simpler, if you really want to use reduce you can use  spread syntax to return a new array or return `acc.concat(age)`

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
]
const newList = List.reduce((acc, {age}) => [...acc, age], []);
// OR
const list2 = List.reduce((acc, {age}) => acc.concat(age), []);
   
console.log(newList);
console.log(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just add **.push(age)**  in `List.reduce`

```js
const List = [
{id:1, name:"jack", sex:"male", age:23},
{id:2, name:"marry", sex:"female", age:18},
{id:3, name:"paul", sex:"male", age:12},
{id:4, name:"katty", sex:"female", age:20}
];

 let myNewData = new Array();
 const newList = List.reduce(
 (acc, {age}) =>{
   myNewData.push(age);
  return myNewData;
  },{});
   
alert(newList);
```